# Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns

Tags: dax

Team,

I'm trying to get the last 12 months of financials, using the days as my base, and am getting the the expression yield error. I think it's because they aren't text, but calculated columns.

What is best to add to this? I tried 'value' and that didn't work. I think the isnonblank may work.. or is blank? As there will be blanks returned.

Here's the formula:

Last 12 Mn Amt = (if('LSI DP_JP_HistorySummaryBySiteMaster'[Z - Days]>=-365,'LSI DP_JP_HistorySummaryBySiteMaster'[Z Total Revenue + Rent Revenue],""))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the TRUE result returns a different data type than the FALSE result.

Try replacing `""` with blank or zero.

```
Last 12 Mn Amt =
IF (
    'LSI DP_JP_HistorySummaryBySiteMaster'[Z - Days] >= -365,
    'LSI DP_JP_HistorySummaryBySiteMaster'[Z Total Revenue + Rent Revenue],
    BLANK ()
)
```

Note: Omitting the 3rd argument entirely returns `BLANK()` as the default behavior.

Comment: Thank you Alexis!  This is helpful. I ended up getting it to work without the blank added, but I'm going to add the blank at so there wont be a broken connection. This feed back helps immensely!