# Error on pulling a date from a whole number column

Tags: dax

Any ideas on how I can re-format this expression to not return an error?

```
Z In-Yr Rate Inc. (Contract Eff.) =
IF (
    'Sales Force_Opportunity'[Z In-Yr Rate Inc. (by Close Dt. Yr)] = "",
    "",
    'Sales Force_Opportunity'[Contract_Effective_Date__c]
)
```

Here's the error

> Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns
> *NOTE: 'sales force opportunity Z in-yr rate inc (by close dt yr) is a whole number and needs to be a whole number if possible*

Comment: So you already asked the same question 11 month ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70297703/expressions-that-yield-variant-data-type-cannot-be-used-to-define-calculated-col. Obviously, there is no help for you.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, you are returning different data types with your expression:

```
If True: return a string
If False: return a date
```

This doesn't work. You have return a date in both cases like so:

```
Z In-Yr Rate Inc. (Contract Eff.) =
IF (
    'Sales Force_Opportunity'[Z In-Yr Rate Inc. (by Close Dt. Yr)] = "",
    DATE(2000, 1, 1),
    'Sales Force_Opportunity'[Contract_Effective_Date__c]
)
```